# Excel - NETWORKDAYS

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to create a formula to give me the NETWORKDAYS between the day 1 of a month and a specific day of the same month.
It works great for the all months of current year but for other years is not working.

Formula used: =NETWORKDAYS(("01/"&MONTH(G2));G2;Holidays!C2:C6)

[image]

Comment: use DATE and do the YEAR also:  `=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(YEAR(G2);MONTH(G2);1);G2;Holidays!C2:C6)` other wise it assumes the current year.

Comment: ^^^ the one above is what you need. Or you can use `EOMONTH()` `=NETWORKDAYS(EOMONTH(F2;-1)+1;F2,;Holidays!C2:C6)`